# ajax "loading" icon with UpdatePanel postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, postback

I have a form that is being dynamically built depending on user selection using Ajax (built in .NET Ajax with UpdatePanel).

how can I insert a "standard" ajax loading icon (maybe have it attached to the mouse pointer) while the postback is happening then remove it when the post back is finished?

I do have the AjaxToolKit installed if that helps.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

use updateprogress of tool kit :hope this will help you

```
<asp:updatepanel id="ResultsUpdatePanel" runat="server">    
<contenttemplate>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <asp:updateprogress id="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" associatedupdatepanelid="ResultsUpdatePanel" dynamiclayout="true">
                        <progresstemplate>

                           <img src="support/images/loading.gif">

                        </progresstemplate>
                    </asp:updateprogress>

                    </div>

 //your control code
</contenttemplate>
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

I found some JavaScript in [this article, 3 Different Ways to Display Progress in an ASP.NET AJAX Application](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=227) by [Suprotim Agarwal](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/author/suprotim-agarwal) to make update process yourself and also you can put it anywhere in page and it work any update panel in page .

> ```html
>     <script type="text/javascript">
>                  // Get the instance of PageRequestManager.
>                  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
>                  // Add initializeRequest and endRequest
>                  prm.add_initializeRequest(prm_InitializeRequest);
>                  prm.add_endRequest(prm_EndRequest);
>                 
>                  // Called when async postback begins
>                  function prm_InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
>                      // get the divImage and set it to visible
>                      var panelProg = $get('divImage');                
>                      panelProg.style.display = '';
>                      // reset label text
>                      var lbl = $get('<%= this.lblText.ClientID %>');
>                      lbl.innerHTML = '';
>      
>                      // Disable button that caused a postback
>                      $get(args._postBackElement.id).disabled = true;
>                  }
>      
>                  // Called when async postback ends
>                  function prm_EndRequest(sender, args) {
>                      // get the divImage and hide it again
>                          $('divImage').hide();                
>                       // Enable button that caused a postback
>                      $get(sender._postBackSettings.sourceElement.id).disabled = false;
>                  }
>              </script>
> ```

Comment: After some limited testing I found there to be a slight delay in the dynamic addition of DOM elements when using the framework's `<asp:updateprogress>` control. Contrarily this method of hooking up the relevant JS events gave instant UI feedback.

Comment: yes its a faster but little bit but if you have a heavy page with lots of dom you can differentiate speeds of both

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProgress" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="loading-panel">
                    <div class="loading-container">
                        <img src="<%= this.ResolveUrl("~/images/gears.gif")%>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <style>
            .loading-panel {
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) none repeat scroll 0 0;
                position: relative;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .loading-container {
                background: rgba(49, 133, 156, 0.4) none repeat scroll 0 0;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 90px;
                height: 100%;
                left: 0;
                padding-top: 15%;
                position: fixed;
                text-align: center;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                z-index: 999999;
            }
        </style>
```

Loading images from:http://loading.io/