# How to display loading.gif when login button is clicked?

Tags: html, asp.net, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a code written in .ascx and also for login button. How display loading.gif before browser takes to the user page? 
Here is the login button code:

```
<div class="login">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>    
     <asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Log In" border="0"   
  style="width:47px; height:20px;Background-color:#24b1d7; float:right; text-align:center; cursor:pointer; font-family:'Lucida Grande',Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif; border:0px;  color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:11px; padding: 1px 0 2px; line-height:0px;" />                                            
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Display "Loading..." message while update panel is updating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704171/asp-net-display-loading-message-while-update-panel-is-updating)

Answer (score 1):

Use the onClick method, to change the text of the button to loading.gif, or use a label whose text is empty, but when the button is clicked, the text changes to the image loading.gif. Then, when the user is validated, give a success event to this method, on which point, if it is a failure, the text changes back to original, and a message is displayed, "Login Unsuccessful", or n the other hand, if it is a success, the page is redirected to the logged in page.