# how to show a moving circle to show process running on a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

Our website has a few long running processes which would be good if we could show a moving circle or hourglass to show the process is running.

I suppose I will need to create a thread but has anyone done something similar before or has an example I could look at?

Comment: For a search engine, you can use google.

Comment: why are people so `Lazy` these days here is a link took a sec to do a google search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704171/asp-net-display-loading-message-while-update-panel-is-updating

Comment: Are you seriously asking if anyone has ever done a spinner or if an example of doing a spinner actually exists?

Comment: Research UpdateProgress control.  Part of Ajax.NET.

Comment: To Karl Anderson, Really?? I've sorted it myself now thank you. You obviously are not busy if you spend your time putting idiotic responses on this website, maybe you should get a life!!

Comment: To DJ KRAZE, I'm not lazy just very busy and thought I might save myself some time, why not just help in future without the comments or just don't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is a busy indicator, take a look at those:

- [Busy Indicator for Ajax Calls](http://forums.asp.net/t/1674608.aspx/1)
- [ASP.NET Busy Indicator](http://forums.asp.net/t/1660210.aspx/1)

Answer (score 1):

Attach some JavaScript on your longrunning process trigger and display an overlay with an gif that shows the busyness. After the process is done you can hide the overlay by adding JS to the page again.