# Gridview loader not working as I want

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my view:

[image: This is my view]

This function show my spinner only on first row edit cell every time even when I clicked on 4th row.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function Grid(spinner) {

         if (spinner == "refNo1") {
             document.getElementById("refNoLoader").style.display = '';
         }

         else if (spinner == "edit") {
             document.getElementById("editLoader").style.display = '';

     }

    </script>
```

I want to display loader on edit button. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display a loading image until a gridview is fully loaded without Ajax Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064079/how-to-display-a-loading-image-until-a-gridview-is-fully-loaded-without-ajax-too)

Comment: you have to get the row index to where is clicked.

Comment: no sir 
i want to dispaly loader image in gridview only in one cell (edit)

Comment: plz can you explain it by example 
i m new in JS

Comment: #Asif sir kindly explain with example

Comment: @nissakhan your question is not clear, so please search what your actual problem is.

Comment: last two days i tried many things but in vain

Comment: #Asif sir can i talk to u on skype ?

Comment: Please do not ask for private one-to-one help; the point of Stack Overflow is that conversations are held in public, so that future readers may benefit. We ask that posters refrain from txtspk and begging too. If you are not getting any answers, perhaps your question could do with some clarification.

Comment: Couple of things: an element id is supposed to be unique for the entire document. Your code does not reference a row number so it couldn't possible change the spinner for a specific row.