# how to display only that data which is currently loaded and in rest shows loading message in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

My application takes 1 minute of time to load because it loads a lot of data while loading the page.I would like to display data which have loaded and display loading message for rest which is not loaded till now,once loaded they should also display data.

In Asp.net how we can do that,Please provide me steps for the same.

Comment: are u use service call ? (scripting)

Comment: yes I call api for loading data

Comment: Learn [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading all data server side You could Load every secion/data of your page by async ajax.
So you will be able to show a loading gif till the content is loaded.

If you want to use server side take a look at the update panel asp.net at [loading updatepanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813590/ajax-loading-icon-with-updatepanel-postbacks)